# Proving that if $A\times A \cong M\times M$ for some A-module M, then $A\times A$ = $N\times M$ for another A-module N

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

I need to show that if M is an A-module and $A\times A$ is isomorphic to $M\times M$ as A-modules then M is a direct summand of $A\times A$.

In other words that $A\times A$ = $N\times M$ for some A-module N.

I'm not sure how to approach proving this result, but I need it as a part of a homological algebra problem I'm working on. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly not going to be true that $A\times A=N\times M$.  Indeed, that would only be possible if $A=N$ and $A=M$, in order for $A\times A$ and $N\times M$ to be equal as sets.

But, that's not what "is a direct summand" means.  If a module $X$ is the direct sum of submodules $Y$ and $Z$, that doesn't mean that $X=Y\times Z$, but that the canonical map $Y\times Z\to X$ is an isomorphism (so in particular $X\cong Y\times Z$).  Moreover, in this context it is certainly not being asserted that $M$ is literally a submodule of $A\times A$ (there is absolutely no reason that $M$ would be a subset of $A\times A$), so what "$M$ is a direct summand of $A\times A$" means is that $M$ is *isomorphic to* a direct summand.

In other words, what you are trying to prove here is just that there exists a module $N$ such that $A\times A\cong N\times M$.  This is now completely trivial: can you see an $N$ that works?